# How do I add control variables when doing SEM in lavaan R?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I was wondering if there is a function to add control variables when doing SEM in `lavaan` conveniently in R?

I would like to test the mediation effect of `WE` between `OSE` and `IWB`. However, if there is another variable `Z` (e.g. `age` or `gender`) that correlates with `WE` and `IWB`, it creates a link - thus, creating correlation between the `WE` and `IWB`. I believe I would need to control for it in order to avoid the bias of the `WE` effect as a mediator.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context or an example?

Comment: I would like to test the mediation effect of WE between OSE and IWB. However if there is another variable Z (e.g. age or gender) that correlates with WE and IWB, it creates a link - thus, creating correlation between the WE and IWB.  I believe I would need to control for it in order to avoid bias of the WE effect as a mediator.

Comment: This will help you: https://paolotoffanin.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/multiple-mediator-analysis-with-lavaan/comment-page-1/
Pay attention to discussions at the bottom of the article. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question, thank you!

Comment: This is an old question that has been resolved, but I thought I would add this to the answer if anyone else comes across this question. On the lavaan website there is an explenation on how to control for a variable, e.g. gender. https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html